# How to put image over div and this image out of the div responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, responsive-images

as you can see in the following image, I want to put an image on the div of my slider and that image is resized responsively and does not change position at the bottom.

[image: Image over div]

the image it's `<div class="img-top">`

```
   <section id="hero-section">  
        <div class="hero-wrapper">                      
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-6 full-height">

                    <div class="img-top">
                        <img src="https://localhost/app/uploads/2021/05/goku_img.png">
                    </div> 
                            
                    <div class="hero-inner">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode(get_field("section_1_left"));?>
                    </div>                              
                 </div><!-- .cell -->

                <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-6 full-height section1right">
                    <div class="hero-inner-right">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode(get_field("section_1_right"));?>
                    </div>                          
                </div><!-- .cell -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- #hero-section -->
```

I don't have css, not have a idea. Thank you for you help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @caiovisk #hero-section{position:absolute;} amd .img-top{ position:relative}

Comment: You are on the way, see CSS positioning docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp . So, `#hero-section` should be relative and `.img-top` absolute. then you can position as you wish... To help you better, please provide us a minimal working example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... we won't code for you

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by adding:

```
#hero-section {
   position: relative;
}
#hero-section .img-top img {
   position: absolute;
}
```